# shell script(AIX) : finding a string after the matched pattern line by line in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I have a log file in AIX environment which has lines like below

```
10.100.108.23 100.10.10.11 - [05/Dec/2012:09:35:27 +0000] "GET /chgs/checkprofile/checkServlet?requestType=signPart1&off=false&oquestions=true&userid=false&source=false&link=%23&country=us&language=en&origin=&displayLayer=no HTTP/1.1" 200 8904 "https://www.test.com/services/request/Home.action" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)" "PD-ERR=; rlang=nl_NL;
```

I need to find the country and language from each line which comes after the pattern `&country` and `&language` respectively. As i am new to shell scripting, i tried to achieve this with grep and awk scripts, but no luck.

Comment: 1. http://whathaveyoutried.com ? (please edit your question). 2. Are you using linux or aix or both? (counting aix as a unix), Aix will require a lowest common-denominator solution unless you have GNU coreutils installed there too.

Comment: Please post the grep and awk scripts you have tried so far, otherwise the question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"&" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/country/ ||$i~/language/){split($i,a,"=");printf a[2]" "}}' your_file
```

Or you can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/.*country=//g;s/language=\([^\&]*\)&.*/\1/g' your_file
```

for removing that ampersand:

```
> sed -e 's/.*country=//g;s/&language=\([^\&]*\)&.*/ \1/g' temp
us en
```

you can read [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: Thank you so much !! The second one gave me the output, but there is an ampersand (&) symbol in between them. How can i remove that?? Can i add an underscore (_) in between.

Comment: You change the tegex to 's/.*country=//g;s/&language=\([^\&]*\)&.*/ \1/g'

Comment: Thanks so much. Your 3rd option worked like charm without '&'. I would like to know the logic behind the pattern. Please let me know where i can learn these.

Comment: @sarathi, you're assuming that `language` immediately follows `country`

Comment: This awk *may* be simpler: `awk -F'[=&? ]' '{for(i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i == "country" || $i == "language") print $(i+1)}'`

Comment: Thank you glenn.. But i would like to have country and language value separately in a single line for each input line. Your code gives them in 2 different lines

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -Eo '(country|language)=[^&]*' file
country=us
language=en

$ grep -Po '(?<=country=|language=)[^&]*' file
us
en

#  Grep Options

-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*country=([^&]*).*language=([^&]*).*/\1 \2/g' file
us en 

# Sed option

-E use extended regular expression
```

Comment: As i am using AIX, -o is not recognized there. Please tell me the usage of o, so that i could find alternative in AIX

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Hope this helps someone who is not using AIX.